# Angular date pipe 'YYYY' doesn't match 'full'

Tags: angular

I'm trying to printout the month and year from a simple string provided by an API. Thus far it has been correct but for `Jan 1st 2022` it prints 2021. I'm running this in New Zealand, where it is currently `GMT+12`, but will be `+13` on every Jan 1st

As seen in the sample below it gets it right in 2020 and 2023, but not 2021 and 2022

Input

```
{{ '2020-01-01' | date : 'full' }} | {{ '2020-01-01' | date : 'MMM YYYY'}}
{{ '2021-01-01' | date : 'full' }} | {{ '2021-01-01' | date : 'MMM YYYY'}}
{{ '2022-01-01' | date : 'full' }} | {{ '2022-01-01' | date : 'MMM YYYY'}}
{{ '2023-01-01' | date : 'full' }} | {{ '2023-01-01' | date : 'MMM YYYY'}}
```

Output

```
Wednesday, January 1, 2020 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+13:00 Jan 2020
Friday, January 1, 2021 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+13:00    Jan 2020
Saturday, January 1, 2022 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+13:00  Jan 2021
Sunday, January 1, 2023 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+13:00    Jan 2023
```

Comment: I believe it is due to the browser settings. Can you check this in different browsers? do you still get the same results?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fast fixed for the problem is that simply change `YYYY` to `yyyy` and everything is going to be OK. **But** note that based on official [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) the letter format for year is `y` not `Y`.

`YYYY` is Week-numbering year format (4 digits or more + zero padded) such as `0002, 0020, 0201, 2017, 20173`.

```
<h3>{{ '2020-01-01' | date : 'full' }} | {{ '2020-01-01' | date : 'MMM yyyy'}}</h3>
<h3>{{ '2021-01-01' | date : 'full' }} | {{ '2021-01-01' | date : 'MMM yyyy'}}</h3>
<h3>{{ '2022-01-01' | date : 'full' }} | {{ '2022-01-01' | date : 'MMM yyyy'}}</h3>
<h3>{{ '2023-01-01' | date : 'full' }} | {{ '2023-01-01' | date : 'MMM yyyy'}}</h3>
```

And the result:

```
Wednesday, January 1, 2020 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+03:30 | Jan 2020
Friday, January 1, 2021 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+03:30 | Jan 2021
Saturday, January 1, 2022 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+03:30 | Jan 2022
Sunday, January 1, 2023 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+03:30 | Jan 2023
```

[ForkedStackBliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-19pt7k?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

But better approach is to use the **name** of each format:

```js
'short': equivalent to 'M/d/yy, h:mm a' (6/15/15, 9:03 AM).
'medium': equivalent to 'MMM d, y, h:mm:ss a' (Jun 15, 2015, 9:03:01 AM).
'long': equivalent to 'MMMM d, y, h:mm:ss a z' (June 15, 2015 at 9:03:01 AM GMT+1).
'full': equivalent to 'EEEE, MMMM d, y, h:mm:ss a zzzz' (Monday, June 15, 2015 at 9:03:01 AM GMT+01:00).
'shortDate': equivalent to 'M/d/yy' (6/15/15).
'mediumDate': equivalent to 'MMM d, y' (Jun 15, 2015).
'longDate': equivalent to 'MMMM d, y' (June 15, 2015).
'fullDate': equivalent to 'EEEE, MMMM d, y' (Monday, June 15, 2015).
'shortTime': equivalent to 'h:mm a' (9:03 AM).
'mediumTime': equivalent to 'h:mm:ss a' (9:03:01 AM).
'longTime': equivalent to 'h:mm:ss a z' (9:03:01 AM GMT+1).
'fullTime': equivalent to 'h:mm:ss a zzzz' (9:03:01 AM GMT+01:00).
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the build-in date like that:

demoDate.ts

```
export class AppComponent  {
  newDate = new Date();
}
```

demoDate.html

```
<h3>{{ newDate | date: 'MMMM yyyy'}}</h3>
<h3>{{ newDate | date: 'MM/yyyy'}}</h3>
<h3>{{ newDate | date: 'dd/MMMM/yyyy'}}</h3>
<h3>{{ newDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</h3>
```

> Form more deep details you can visit https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Here is the stackblitz example link [Example Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ssfm5c?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because you used Week-numbering year format `YYYY`.

The `YYYY` represents Week-numbering year, here i guess you don't need the Week-numbering year, so you can just use the `yyyy`.

[format YYYY vs yyyy doc](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#description)

Update

```
YYYY
```

to lower case will solve the issue.

```
yyyy
```

like:

```
{{ '2022-01-01' | date : 'MMM yyyy'}}
```

[Week-numbering year also called ISO year informally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date)

Comment: Thank you for translating "week-numbering year" to "ISO year"!